# ImageView OnClickListener not working with layout_gravity bottom

Tags: android, layout, onclick, imageview, gravity

I have the following layout containing ImageView imageView2, which I want to be completely clickable.

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have an OnClickListener set to imageView2. I want the whole image to be clickable. This works fine. However, whenever I add android:layout_gravity="bottom", only the top border of the image remains clickable. However, I want the whole image to be clickable.

How can I get imageView2 to be completely clickable with layout_gravity="bottom"?

I also tried moving the gravity to the parent

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This did not work either.

Comment: what container do you have this in? RelativeLayout , LinearLayout or FrameLayout?

Comment: parent is a LinearLayout

Comment: try to clean and rebuild. I am not seeing why this would be an issue, may want to try to define android:layout_gravity="bottom" for both of the images since they are horizontal and both have the same weight and height params.

Comment: Neither cleaning nor setting the other image to android:layout_gravity="bottom" worked. Still only part of the image is clickable when using that flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your entire ImageView wouldn't be clickable. Seems like it should just work. But maybe you can just try wrapping the ImageView inside a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Or, (as I mentioned in comments) try loading your image using background instead of src, then remove the `adjustViewBounds` attribute. I'm guessing that's probably what's causing the strange OnClick behavior:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

Comment: I tried this as well. Unfortunately, the same effect. I am still referencing the ImageView from the OnClickListener, or should I reference the FrameLayout instead?

Comment: Yes, onClick on the FrameLayout.

Comment: @barq, did you try the OnClick on the FrameLayout? If that doesn't work, I think you may need just use `background` instead of `src` on your ImageView, and remove your `adjustViewBounds`. I'm guessing that attribute (adjustViewBounds) is throwing something off.